# Replace string to a file based from an imported CSV column

Tags: powershell, csv

How can I replace string in a loop to myfile.xml based from an external CSV column?

myfile.xml contains:

```
<User Name="USER1">
            <Option Name="Pass">45E4EDE</Option>
            <Option Name="Salt">P&amp;</Option>
            <Option Name="Group"></Option>
            <Option Name="Bypass server userlimit">0</Option>
            <Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>
            <Option Name="IP Limit">0</Option>
            <Option Name="Enabled">1</Option>
        /User>
<User Name="USER2">
            <Option Name="Pass">4533EDE</Option>
            <Option Name="Salt">P&/Option>
            <Option Name="Group"></Option>
            <Option Name="Bypass server userlimit">0</Option>
            <Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>
            <Option Name="IP Limit">0</Option>
            <Option Name="Enabled">1</Option>
        /User>
<User Name="USER3">
            <Option Name="Pass">733EDE</Option>
            <Option Name="Salt">P&/Option>
            <Option Name="Group"></Option>
            <Option Name="Bypass server userlimit">0</Option>
            <Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>
            <Option Name="IP Limit">0</Option>
            <Option Name="Enabled">1</Option>
        /User>
```

external mycsv.csv contains:

```
Users,Comments,HomeDir
USER1,account1,c:\folder1
USER2,account2,c:\folder2
USER3,account3,c:\folder3
```

I need foreach USER in 'Users' column to replace `"Enabled">1` with `"Enabled">0` in myfile.xml.
Probably I need some code like `Select-String $_.Users -Context 0,7` but I need a hint.
Thanks

Comment: The xml is not good (many errors) and you will not be able to convert it into an internal object for further processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you fix the errors in the XML you show us (no root tag, various closing tags not having an opening `<`, values `P&` should be `"P&amp;"`), you can do this:

Using Case-sensitive XPath

```
[xml]$xml = @"
<root>
    <User Name="USER1">
        <Option Name="Pass">45E4EDE</Option>
        <Option Name="Salt">"P&amp;"</Option>
        <Option Name="Group"></Option>
        <Option Name="Bypass server userlimit">0</Option>
        <Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>
        <Option Name="IP Limit">0</Option>
        <Option Name="Enabled">1</Option>
    </User>
    <User Name="USER2">
        <Option Name="Pass">4533EDE</Option>
        <Option Name="Salt">"P&amp;"</Option>
        <Option Name="Group"></Option>
        <Option Name="Bypass server userlimit">0</Option>
        <Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>
        <Option Name="IP Limit">0</Option>
        <Option Name="Enabled">1</Option>
    </User>
    <User Name="USER3">
        <Option Name="Pass">733EDE</Option>
        <Option Name="Salt">"P&amp;"</Option>
        <Option Name="Group"></Option>
        <Option Name="Bypass server userlimit">0</Option>
        <Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>
        <Option Name="IP Limit">0</Option>
        <Option Name="Enabled">1</Option>
    </User>
</root>
"@
```

```
# loop though the usernames in the CSV, find the node and if found set Enabled to value '0'
foreach ($user in (Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\test.csv').Users) {
    $node = $xml.root.SelectSingleNode("//User[@Name='$user']/Option[@Name='Enabled']")
    if ($node) { $node.InnerText = '0' }
}
# save the updated xml file
$xml.Save("D:\Test\test.xml")
```

Or use Case-Insensitive 'dotted' method

```
# loop though the usernames in the CSV, find the node and if found set Enabled to value '0'
foreach ($user in (Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\test.csv').Users) {
    $xml.root.User | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $user } | ForEach-Object {
        ($_.Option | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'Enabled' }).'#text' = '0'
    }
}
# save the updated xml file
$xml.Save("D:\Test\test.xml")
```

Both methods yield this XML file as result

```
<root>
  <User Name="USER1">
    <Option Name="Pass">45E4EDE</Option>
    <Option Name="Salt">"P&amp;"</Option>
    <Option Name="Group">
    </Option>
    <Option Name="Bypass server userlimit">0</Option>
    <Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>
    <Option Name="IP Limit">0</Option>
    <Option Name="Enabled">0</Option>
  </User>
  <User Name="USER2">
    <Option Name="Pass">4533EDE</Option>
    <Option Name="Salt">"P&amp;"</Option>
    <Option Name="Group">
    </Option>
    <Option Name="Bypass server userlimit">0</Option>
    <Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>
    <Option Name="IP Limit">0</Option>
    <Option Name="Enabled">0</Option>
  </User>
  <User Name="USER3">
    <Option Name="Pass">733EDE</Option>
    <Option Name="Salt">"P&amp;"</Option>
    <Option Name="Group">
    </Option>
    <Option Name="Bypass server userlimit">0</Option>
    <Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>
    <Option Name="IP Limit">0</Option>
    <Option Name="Enabled">0</Option>
  </User>
</root>
```